# How would you say "he's flexing his arms" or "she flexes her arm" in Japanese?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I've been having a hard trying to find how to say this in Japanese without it sounding weird. I don't know enough Japanese to say it which is why I wanted to know if anyone knew. As in, "he's flexing his arms in the video" or "she flexes her arm in the picture".

Comment: Related/duplicate? [What is the Japanese verb for "to flex" (one's muscles)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56748/5464)

Answer (score 7):

It is far from a multi-purpose replacement for the phrase "flex one's arm", but if you mean a specific kind of pose below, we usually say 力{ちから}こぶを作る.

力{ちから}こぶ ("force bulge") is the word for the bumped muscle when you put your strength on that body part, and typically refers to that of biceps.

[image: flex arms]

[image: 力こぶを作る]